# Unified XAML for WPF and Silverlight using T4?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, t4

I am writing code that is used in both WPF and Silverlight. In C# I can use `"#if SILVERLIGHT"` for conditional compilation, and it works.

In XAML, however, I must resort to use completely different XAML files, since some attributes are simply incompatible. XAML files are 99% a like, and keeping them in sync is a hassle.

I would like to convert them into a T4 template, so I can do things like:

```
<SomeControl <#=ClipsToBounds()#> />
```

Where `ClipsToBounds()` produces different text for WPF and Silverlight. The requirements are:

- Intellisense while working on the XAML
- Templates generated at build time
- The project must be self contained and work on stock version of Visual Studio: installs of various SDKs and 3rd party editors are not
  acceptable
- Results of the template run should NOT be in source control. -

I found that I can change `custom tool` on a XAML file from `MSBuild:Compile to  TextTemplatingFileGenerator` and I don't lose Intellisense. However, resulting templates are generated at design time. To have then generated at build time seems like a big pain.

Did anyone have successful experience with this kind of setup?

Comment: Isn't using a portable class library an option?

Comment: Portable class libraries solve the problem of shared non-UI code, they should be a good fit for the ViewModel layer if using MVVM, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

Only the generic user controls which have generic behaviors across the platforms can be placed in PCL , However,the best suggestion would be keeping separate xaml views for each platform .

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody seems to have suggested a template based solution as desired, I'll share some experience of working with projects targetting both SL/WPF. Many people will suggest using two completely separate XAML files, a different view per-platform, and in many ways this is the "purist" thing to do. But if you want to eliminate duplication, and reduce the risk of your 2 targets drifting apart, I'd certainly suggest sharing the XAML files (with simple project links) can work acceptably well.

There are a few common incompatibilities:

- Controls exist in both platforms in different namespaces - subclass your own version and refer to that.
- Styles etc. need differ between platforms - include a common dictionary of resources, different per platform, and reference by key.
- Controls are substantially different, or present in only 1 platform - introduce your own wrapper control (which may require substantial implementation in the 'missing' case).
- Basic properties or functonality missing - can often hack something up with an attached behaviour (eg your ClipsToBounds example is found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36495/Silverlight-ClipToBounds-Can-I-Clip-It-Yes-You-Can)).